# Help using crontab to play a sound

Tags: sound, cron

I want to use crontab to play recordings of the big Ben every hour and at 15,30 and 45 minutes.

So far I'm using mplayer2 and the following tasks:

```
0 1,13 * * * mplayer -really-quiet ~/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_01.ogg -volume 100 >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_75
0 2,14 * * * mplayer -really-quiet ~/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_02.ogg -volume 100 >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_76
0 3,15 * * * mplayer -really-quiet  ~/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_03.ogg -volume 100 >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_77
0 4,16 * * * mplayer -really-quiet  ~/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_04.ogg -volume 100 >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_78
0 5,17 * * * mplayer -really-quiet  ~/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_05.ogg -volume 100 >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_79
0 6,18 * * * mplayer -really-quiet  ~/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_06.ogg -volume 100 >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_80
0 7,19 * * * mplayer -really-quiet  ~/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_07.ogg -volume 100 >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_81
0 8,20 * * * mplayer -really-quiet  ~/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_08.ogg -volume 100 >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_82
0 9,21 * * * mplayer -really-quiet  ~/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_09.ogg -volume 100 >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_83
0 10,22 * * * mplayer -really-quiet  ~/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_10.ogg -volume 100 >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_84
0 11,23 * * * mplayer -really-quiet ~/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_11.ogg -volume 100 >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_85
0 0,12 * * * mplayer -really-quiet ~/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_12.ogg -volume 100 >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_86
15 0-23 * * * mplayer -really-quiet ~/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_15-1.ogg -volume 100 >/dev/null 2>&1
30 0-23 * * * mplayer -really-quiet ~/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_15-2.ogg -volume 100 >/dev/null 2>&1
45 0-23 * * * mplayer -really-quiet ~/bin/bigben    /Clock_Chime_15-3.ogg -volume 100 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

But most of the time it does not work. Sometimes it does play the sound but delayed. ie. supposed to play at 21:15, and it didn't at 21:17 I opened a terminal and played another file with mplayer, after it finished, I heard the one supposed to play 2 min earlier.

Edit:
Now trying with:
    `* * * * * "/usr/bin/mplayer -volume 100 --ao=pulse /home/myuser/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_15-1.ogg"` without success.

I do have the feeling like the task stays in some kind of cue.

PS. I can share the sound files.

Comment: When *does* it work? How about sending the output to a file, instead of `/dev/null`, so that you can see evidence of each invocation. Log `stderr` also.

Comment: I'm not proficient in the terminal, `>/dev/null 2>&1`  is something I added a long time ago trying to hide the terminal that poped up when playing the sound. Based on your coment I did removed `>/dev/null` and it worked , however I really do not know how or why, and if it was just a coincidence.

Comment: Is working as long as no other sound is playing, and does not show on the pulse audio volume control. `* * * * * mplayer -volume 100 --ao=pulse ~/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_15-2.ogg 2>&1`

Comment: This last comment is a critical bit of info for the question. It should not be a comment it should be added to the question with edit.

Answer (score 14):

As per this answer: [Can I use cron to chime at top of hour like a grandfather clock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832072/can-i-use-cron-to-chime-at-top-of-hour-like-a-grandfather-clock/832266#832266) you need to export an environment variable before playing sounds in your cron script:

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
```

So rather than calling your music player directly, call a script name in `crontab` like this:

```
0 1,13 * * * /home/ME/bin/big-ben.sh /home/ME/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_01.ogg >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_75
    (... SNIP ...)
45 0-23 * * * /home/ME/bin/big-ben.sh /home/ME/bin/bigben/Clock_Chime_15-3.ogg >/dev/null 2>&1
```

- Replace `ME` with your user name.
- You had an error (the spaces after `/bigben` and before `/Clock` on in the last line of your `crontab`. I've fixed the error above.
- You were using `~/` shortcut for `/home/ME` which `cron` doesn't like. Use full path names in `cron`.

---

Then create your `/usr/local/bin/big-ben.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
mplayer -really-quiet "$1" -volume 100
```

- "$1" is the parameter 1 passed by `crontab` entry to your script

Remember to mark the script executable by using:

```
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/big-ben.sh
```

Comment: I know this was two years ago, but I'm still struggling with a similar problem, getting a cron job to play a sound that works just fine straight from the command line.  You have two different paths listed for the script.  Does it matter which one is used?

Comment: With the fix, it works for me.

Comment: Ufff... Saved my day. Thank you. This is the perfect solution for the problem and works pretty fine on 20.04 as well.

Comment: Great! Still works on Ubuntu 23.10

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command to play a sound file:

```
 aplay ~/scripts/KenbeepBent.wav
```

where `KenbeepBent.wav` is a sound file I keep in my ~/scripts directory so I can include it in bash scripts. I expect it would meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just add & at the end of the command line. That forces the program to quit after it has executed. It worked for me

Comment: As written this is not an answer. An answer is a complete solution. What command line? Why would I want to force the program to quit?